# Settings API callback function inserts html quotes from nowhere

Tags: php, html, settings-api, callbacks

currently I try to write a callback for a Wordpress option of my theme with the settings API. This is my function:

```
    function background_callback($args){
    printf(
        'Picture 
         <input 
               type="radio" 
               name="%1$s[%2$s]" 
               onclick= "showChoosenField("%3$s")" 
               value="<?php checked("%3$s", get_option("%1$s[%2$s]"), true); ?>"
          />
         <input 
               type="radio" 
               name="%1$s[%2$s]" 
               onclick= "showChoosenField("%4$s")" 
               value="<?php checked("%4$s", get_option("%1$s[%2$s]"), true); ?>"
          />   
         Color
         <p></p>
         <label for="%2$s">%5$s / %3$s/ %4$s</label>',
        $args['option_name'],
        $args['namePic_Color'],
        $args['valuePic'],
        $args['valueColor'],
        $args['description']
        );
    }
```

But when I look at the browser I get this output:

```
<td>"Picture"
    <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="header_options_group[img_color_name]" 
          onclick="showChoosenField(" ")" 
          value="<?php checked(" ", get_option("header_options_group[img_color_name]"), true); ?>
          ""
    />"
    <input 
          type="radio" 
          name="header_options_group[img_color_name]" 
          onclick="showChoosenField(" ")" 
          value="<?php checked(" ", get_option("header_options_group[img_color_name]"), true); ?>
          ""
    /> Color" 
    <p></p>
    <label for="img_color_name">
          Please check if you want a Picture or a color. / / 
    </label>
</td>
```

From where are the quotes at the end of the  at the line 7,8 and 14,15?
I tried so many things to get rid of this things.
But no matter what I change they stay there, or some other quotes appear at another places.
I concatinated every thing, deleted different parts, but no way.

I assume its because the php in the printf.
Did someone know why this happens?
Or if its because the php how I can change it that it works?
I have no ideas anymore.
Thank you.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168298/how-to-output-a-string-with-a-double-quotation-mark

Comment: @Ranuka Never mind, it works with that `'<input type="radio" name="%1$s[%2$s]" onclick= "showChoosenField(\'%3$s\')" value="<?php checked(\'%3$s\', get_option(\'%1$s[%2$s]\'), true); ?>"/>'`. Thank you very much !

Comment: i think the problem is coming from the $args variables you passing into printf() function , try replace them to normal string. eg.  'option_name','color','pic','valuecolor',   'description' ); lets try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to escape the quotation marks like this.

```
<input type="radio" name="%1$s[%2$s]" onclick= "showChoosenField(\'%3$s\')" value="<?php checked(\'%3$s\', get_option(\'%1$s[%2$s]\'), true); ?>"/>
```